# Como definir o tamanho máximo de disco de um banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Como definir o tamanho máximo de disco de um banco de dados MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL ou DB2?

Essa é a forma como faço no SQL Server:

```
Create Database MyDatabase
on (Name='MyDatabase_Data',
    Filename='c:\db\BdUnisanta_Data.mdf',
    Size= 20MB,
    FileGrowth = 10%,
    Maxsize=100MB)
log on 
    (Name = 'MyDatabase_log',
     Filename = 'c:\db\MyDatabase_Log.ldf',
     Size = 5MB,
     FileGrowth = 5%,
     MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
     )
```

Como poderia fazer isso nesses bancos de dados?

Comment: O tamanho maximo?

Comment: Sim, o tamanho máximo que eu possa gravar nele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada banco de dados tem sua forma de limitar o tamanho, ou não.

## MYSQL

O MySQL não oferece um sistema que permita limitar o tamanho da base de dados com [Create Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html) conforme seu exemplo. Uma das formas de resolver isso é usar o InnoDB como o motor da base de dados e definir a configuração [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) para valores próximos ao desejável de arquivos por tabela que provavelmente funcionaria para limitar o crescimento das tabelas além de um limite calculável. Além disso o InnoDB mantém os dados em um arquivo(s) definido(s) pela propriedade [innodb_data_file_path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_data_file_path) e também pode ser limitado seu tamanho máximo através da configuração, porém essa propriedade não pode ser alterada em bancos já instalados.

Infelizmente eu não vejo uma maneira prática de conseguir o que você quer. Se você estiver preocupado com o uso de espaço em disco excedendo os limites predefinidos e não quiser seguir o caminho dos regulamentos de cotas externas, sugiro ficar com as configurações de espaço de tabela combinadas (e não innodb_file_per_table) e remover o autoextend da configuração innodb_data_file_path ou definir um maxsize (ex. ibdata1:16M:autoextend:max:1GB)

Mesmo assim você ainda não será capaz de obter limites específicos de cada usuário ou schemas mas pelo menos vai impedir que o espaço ocupado pelas tabela cresça além de seu tamanho inicial nesta configuração. Ainda, e infelizmente, não há nenhuma maneira de configurar um tamanho para cada um dos esquemas de forma individualizada.

## Oracle

O Oracle é um banco de dados que já foi muito testado no meio empresarial e escalabilidade e controle de tamanhos em disco foi muito bem explorado.
Existem [diversas configurações que visam definir o tamanho físico do banco de dados no disco](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits002.htm#i287915) e para [controlar a quota de cada usuário](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch19s09s02.html).

O próprio exemplo do [Create Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create003.htm#ADMIN11080) da documentação mostra como é possível definir tamanhos dos arquivos da base de dados:

```
CREATE DATABASE mynewdb
   USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY sys_password
   USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY system_password
   LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo01.log') SIZE 100M,
           GROUP 2 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo02.log') SIZE 100M,
           GROUP 3 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/redo03.log') SIZE 100M
   MAXLOGFILES 5
   MAXLOGMEMBERS 5
   MAXLOGHISTORY 1
   MAXDATAFILES 100
   CHARACTER SET US7ASCII
   NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16
   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
   DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/system01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
   SYSAUX DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
   DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
      DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/users01.dbf'
      SIZE 500M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
   DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tempts1
      TEMPFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/temp01.dbf'
      SIZE 20M REUSE
   UNDO TABLESPACE undotbs
  DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/mynewdb/undotbs01.dbf'
  SIZE 200M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

> Você pode definir vários limites durante a criação do banco de dados.
>   Alguns desses limites são restringidos e afetados pelos limites do
>   sistema operacional. Por exemplo, se você definir MAXDATAFILES, o
>   Oracle Database aloca espaço suficiente no arquivo de controle para
>   armazenar MAXDATAFILES nomes de arquivo, mesmo se o banco de dados
>   tiver apenas um arquivo de dados inicialmente. No entanto, como o
>   tamanho máximo do arquivo de controle é limitado e dependente do
>   sistema operacional, talvez não seja possível definir todos os
>   parâmetros CREATE DATABASE em seus máximos teóricos. Para obter mais
>   informações sobre como definir limites durante a criação do banco de
>   dados, consulte o Oracle Database SQL Language Reference e a
>   documentação Oracle específica do sistema operacional.

## PostgreSQL

Na [documentação oficial nada indica que há suporte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html) direto no PostgreSQL para realizar essa restrição.
Existem workarounds por aí que usam até mesmo [triggers para limitar o tamanho de linhas em uma tabela](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20145/possible-to-keep-max-number-of-records-in-postgresql). Ou até mesmo usando tabalespaces dentro de "VolumeGroup" do linux, em listas de e-mail limitar o uso através de grupos de volume foi considerado como "[Um desastre esperando para acontecer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20080703191736.GB24555%40easy2.in-chemnitz.de)", apesar de ser uma solução que pode funcionar.

## DB2

O TABLESPACE no DB2 tem um atributo MAXSIZE que pode ser usado para especificar atributos de tamanho físico na instrução [CREATE DATABASE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html) (ou ao criar TABLESPACE  adicionais) ou use [ALTER TABLESPACE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000890.html) para defini-los posteriormente.

> **MAXIZIZE** 
>   Especifica o tamanho máximo no qual um TABLESPACE habilitado
>   para redimensionamento automático pode ser aumentado automaticamente.
>   Se o TABLESPACE é redimensionável automaticamente, mas a cláusula
>   MAXSIZE não é especificada, o padrão é NONE.

Utilizando o valor "NONE" (padrão), define que o TABLESPACE é permitido crescer até a capacidade do sistema de arquivos ou para o tamanho máximo do TABLESPACE(definido pelo tamanho e número de paginações).

Então, a propriedade MAXSIZE no CREATE DATABASE pode ser usado para especificar um limite no tamanho por banco de dados, ao qual um TABLESPACE  de armazenamento automático pode ser aumentado automaticamente. 
O valor inteiro deve ser seguido por K (para kilobytes), M (para megabytes) ou G (para gigabytes).

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase
   automatic storage yes
   on C:\mydb
   user tablespace managed by automatic storage
      initialsize 20 M increasesize 10 percent MAXSIZE 100 M;
```